# Laravel images not Writeable created with Intervention/image

Tags: php, laravel, image-processing, intervention

I am working With Intervention/Image, It create some images. when i try this from saved path,

```
Image::make(storage_path('app/'.$photo->path));
```

gives,

Image source not readable.

Answer (score 0):

first check to see if you have permission problems then check to see if you have done php artisan storage:link

Comment: I have to store content in storage/app/uploads but storage:link add for storage/app/public.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you brother! I just got it,
it is permission's problem, where Intervention/Image object was creating folder while storing file to related path.

```
$DesPath = "uploads/photos/u{$user->id}/{$dateFolder}/p{$ran}/";
```

The solution is to create those directories in the path before save file in it.
so i did this before $img->save() and it worked!.

```
Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory(storage_path('app/'.$DesPath));
```

before

```
$img->save(storage_path('app/'.$DesPath).$filename);
```